# On the upper bound estimation of $D(N)$ in Chen Jingrun's theorem

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

What are the current research results on the estimation of the upper bound of $D(N)$ in Chen Jingrun's theorem?

Including but not limited to Chen Jingrun's improvement 7.8342 and Wu Jie's improvement 7.8209.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KVCy.png)

Comment: It would be better if you clarify the definition of $D(N)$

Comment: I do not know about $D(N)$, but the state-of-the-art for the related twin prime problem is Lichtman's recent preprint on twin primes, building on Maynard's work, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.02851 . The table in p. 3 lists previous works, including Chen's.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what I want to get is the upper bound estimation of $D(N)$. All the information you mentioned in this article is about the upper bounds on $π_2 (x)/Π(x)$.

Comment: In addition, how to modify the weight in the weighted sieve method?